# Iterating an operator on a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, iteration

I want to be able to build an operator $S$, on a polynomial in multiple variables which does something like this

$f[x,y] =$ some polynomial

$S[f][x,y] = y*f[y,x]$

And then for a specific choice of $n$, I would like to see the results of $S^k[f]$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n$.

I am very new to Mathematica, practically a baby, so I would appreciate as syntactically simple an explanation as possible.

Comment: You can type almost literally what you have written in the question: Try `S[f_][x_,y_]:=y*f[y,x]` (see [`Blank`/`_`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) and [`SetDelayed`/`:=`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)), and take a look at [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) and [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html)

Comment: Alternatively, `S[expr_]:=y*(expr/.{x->y,y->x}); Rest[NestList[S,x^5+y^7,6]]`.